# Is it possible to place a embed video when asking a question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Just wondering if it is possible to put / embed video together with question? Currently, we can add a image to it but sometime, the problem that a user face might be complicated enough that a video would be better to describe the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think embedding a video is supported explicitly. Just include a link to the video in your question.

Comment: I was thinking like other website (e.g. blog) where video are embed so that user do not need to click a particular link to go to that website - the user will still remain at the current site to watch the video and they can answer it without flipping thru the tabs (if the link they open, open a new tab). Probably would be nice if future version of stackexchange have.